# Mongodb query specific month|year not date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How can I query a specific month in mongodb, not date range, I need month to make a list of customer birthday for current month.

In SQL will be something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE MONTH(bday)='09'
```

Now I need to translate that in mongodb.
Note: My dates are already saved in MongoDate type, I used this thinking that will be easy to work before but now I can't find easily how to do this simple thing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do that using `aggregate` with the [`$month`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/month/#exp._S_month) projection operator:

```js
db.customer.aggregate([
  {$project: {name: 1, month: {$month: '$bday'}}},
  {$match: {month: 9}}
]);
```

Comment: Thats what I need. But now I have a little problem:
"exception: can't convert from BSON type EOO to Date" errorCode: 16006

I believe thats because some documents don't have the field bday. So, how can I use $project with the $exists operator making the query only with the documents that have the field $bday?

Comment: Add a `$match` to the beginning of your pipeline that uses `$exists` to filter the docs before they get to the `$project`.

Comment: Now works perfect, here the final query: https://gist.github.com/lslucas/d95767f8da0013bb92a4

Comment: Just to share my pain. Becareful of what you match against. I was matching a string until I realised that $project $month is returning a Number.

Comment: how can i add `month` to `$project` without loosing other fields in the response?

Answer (score 33):

With MongoDB 3.6 and newer, you can use the **[`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)** operator in your **[`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** query. This allows you to build query expressions that compare fields from the same document in a **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** stage.

```
db.customer.find({ "$expr": { "$eq": [{ "$month": "$bday" }, 9] } })
```

---

For other MongoDB versions, consider running an aggregation pipeline that uses the **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** operator as it allows you to incorporate with a single pipeline, a functionality with **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** to create a field that represents the month of a date field and **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** to filter the documents
which match the given condition of the month being September.

In the above, **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** uses **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** tenary operator as means to provide the conditional expression that will create the system variable which does the redaction. The logical expression in **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** will check
for an equality of a date operator field with a given value, if that matches then **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** will return the documents using the **[`$$KEEP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep)** system variable and discards otherwise using **[`$$PRUNE`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune)**.

Running the following pipeline should give you the desired result:

```
db.customer.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "bday": { "$exists": true } } },
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [{ "$month": "$bday" }, 9] },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

---

This is similar to a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** +**[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** combo but you'd need to then select all the rest of the fields that go into the pipeline:

```
db.customer.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "bday": { "$exists": true } } },
    {
        "$project": {
            "month": { "$month": "$bday" },
            "bday": 1,
            "field1": 1,
            "field2": 1,
            .....
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "month": 9 } }
])
```

---

With another alternative, albeit slow query, using the **[`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** method with **[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)** as:

```
db.customer.find({ "$where": "this.bday.getMonth() === 8" })
```

Comment: I had never seen $redact anywhere before. Thanks for the tip, that will be super useful.

Comment: Last one performance is not for production but is very handy for daily use :) thanks! (plus you need to remember to subtract a number to match getMonth)

Comment: `{ "$where": "this.bday.getMonth() === 8" }` In this query, can I use `$in`? I have an array of months like [2, 4,7]. If `bday.getMonth()` equal to any value of my array, I want that record

Comment: @Mr.7 What is your MongoDB version? If 3.6 then `db.collection.find({ "$expr": { "$in": [{ "$month": "$bday" }, [2, 4,7]] } })` otherwise `db.collection.find({ "$where": "[2, 4, 7].indexOf(this.bday.getMonth()) >= 0" })`

Comment: Thank you for this, very helpful!

Comment: @chridam I have used your answer `db.customer.find({ "$where": "this.bday.getMonth() === 8" })` but it gives the error like  **$where not allowed in this atlas tier**

How to solve it

Answer (score 9):

First, you need to check whether the data type is in ISODate.
IF not you can change the data type as the following example.

```
db.collectionName.find().forEach(function(each_object_from_collection){each_object_from_collection.your_date_field=new ISODate(each_object_from_collection.your_date_field);db.collectionName.save(each_object_from_collection);})
```

Now you can find it in two ways

```
db.collectionName.find({ $expr: {
$eq: [{ $year: "$your_date_field" }, 2017]
}});
```

Or by aggregation

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([{$project: {field1_you_need_in_result: 1,field12_you_need_in_result: 1,your_year_variable: {$year: '$your_date_field'}, your_month_variable: {$month: '$your_date_field'}}},{$match: {your_year_variable:2017, your_month_variable: 3}}]);
```

Comment: omg thank you so much, you saved my day with this $eq expression Abdul!!!!!

Comment: Hi @ABDUL How can I add the month in below query db.collectionName.find({ $expr: {
$eq: [{ $year: "$your_date_field" }, 2017, { $month: "$your_date_field" }, 2]
}});

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can fetch this result within date like this ,

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
          $and: [
              {
                "$eq": [
                  {
                   "$month": "$date"
                 },
                  3
             ]
           },
           {
             "$eq": [
                 {
               "$year": "$date"
                },
                2020
               ]
             }
          ]
         }
        })
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're concerned about efficiency, you may want to store the month data in a separate field within each document.