# MongoDB Find Query by year

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

How to perform a `find()` operation with a condition like `{fromdt: 2016}` where `fromdt` is an `ISODate` in the backend. After checking stackoverflow posts, I could see only one option that uses `$year` with aggregation. But basically it uses projection and I dont get all fields in the document. So I would like to know how to achieve this without aggregation? Basically I want to apply the mentioned filter and get all documents with **all** fields in each.

example document:

```
{
"_id" : 501.0,
"custid" : 1.0,
"fromdt" : ISODate("2016-01-23T00:00:00.000Z"),
"enddt" : ISODate("2017-01-22T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

Is there a better way without having to remember the format `2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z` by just giving the year value filter as 2016?

Comment: Try `db.col.find({ "$expr": { "$eq": [{ "$year": "$fromdt" }, 2016] } })` in 3.6

Comment: Its similar. You just need to use year instead of month. Look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42513078/2683814). Is that not what you want ?

Comment: Thanks for your response, will post if that works.

Comment: It worked :) +1

Answer (score 12):

You can try this, Date between 2016-01-01 to 2017-01-01

```
db.getCollection('TEST').find({
    "fromdt": {
        $gte: ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, is there a better way without having to remember the format `2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`?