# How to use $month as part of logical operators in MongoDB in Java?

Tags: mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-java-3.3.0

I have a document `{_id: abc, orderdate:(ISO date), quantity:10}`
and I am trying to come up with query in Java where we search for all documents with orders in a given month whose `quantity` is `> 5`
Eg: `select * from documents where  month(orderdate)=Jan and quantity>5`

Can you please help me write this query in Java?

Answer (score 0):

After going thru [Search by month in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907566/mongodb-query-specific-monthyear-not-date)

I learnt about $expr from `db.customer.find({ "$expr": { "$eq": [{ "$month": "$bday" }, 9] } })` and converted to

```
db.getCollection('customer').find({
"$and":[{"$expr": { "$eq": [{ "$month": "$bday" }, 9] }},{"firstName":"John"}]
})
```

and then get java code using

`Document.parser("db.getCollection('custoer').find({"$and":[{"$expr": { "$eq": [{ "$month": "$bday" }, 9] }},{"firstName":"John"}]})")`

at the end java code looks like

`Filters.and(Arrays.asList(Filters.expr(new Document().append("$in", Arrays.asList(new Document().append("$month", "$bday"),9))),Filters.eq("firstName","John")))`