# Display field document in mongoDB after execute Query aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is an example of a data document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f437e7846103b2ad0fc5d7d"),
    "order_no" : "O-200824-AGFJDQW",
    "shipment_no" : "S-200824-AGWCRRM",
    "member_id" : 2200140,
    "ponta_id" : "9990010100280214",
    "plu" : 14723,
    "product_name" : "AQUA Air Mineral Botol Air Pet 600ml",
    "qty" : 2,
    "store_id" : "TD46",
    "stock_on_hand" : 0,
    "transaction_date" : ISODate("2020-08-24T08:28:29.931Z"),
    "created_date" : ISODate("2020-08-24T08:46:48.441Z")
}
```

this is the data query that I run

```
var bulan = 12 //month is written with number. example: August = 8
db.log_stock_oos.aggregate([
  {
      $project: {
          month: {
              $month: '$transaction_date'
              }
          }
  },
  {
      $match: {month: bulan}
  }
]);
```

but the result is like this after I run the query

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f44689607fe453fbfba433e"),
    "month" : 12
}
```

how to make the output exactly like the document display that I attached above??
[this is my reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18908725/11640072)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the projection, its kind of if your value `1` then include the field, if your value `0` then exclude the field from the whole documents. [Projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

You can do two things

**Use the projection**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      month: {
        $month: "$transaction_date"
      },
      order_no: 1,
      shipment_no: 1,
      member_id: 1,
      //other fields like above with the value 1
    }
  },
  // match stages
])
```

**Use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/)**

use $addFields incited of $project in your code. If will create a filed if not exists in your document, else it will overwrite the field