# MongoDB Aggregate - Query to get items that match key in first item of sort

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

We have the following records in a collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("1"), "date" : ISODate("2017-02-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("2"), "date" : ISODate("2017-02-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("3"), "date" : ISODate("2017-03-03T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4"), "date" : ISODate("2017-02-02T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5"), "date" : ISODate("2017-03-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6"), "date" : ISODate("2017-02-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("7"), "date" : ISODate("2017-01-02T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("8"), "date" : ISODate("2017-01-03T00:00:00Z") }
```

How to filter the most recent records by `$month` of `date` field like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("3"), "date" : ISODate("2017-03-03T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5"), "date" : ISODate("2017-03-01T00:00:00Z") }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongodb query specific month|year not date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907566/mongodb-query-specific-monthyear-not-date)

Comment: We don't know the latest `$month` value until sort. After sort we don't know how to compare the top record's date in next aggregate step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `$group` - Group by the first day of the month year from `date` and add documents into `data` array.
2. `$sort` - Sort by `_id` DESC.
3. `$skip`
4. `$limit` - Take the first document from the result.
5. `$unwind` - Deconstruct the `data` array to multiple documents.
6. `$replaceWith` -  Replace the document with `data` document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "$dateFromParts": {
          "year": {
            $year: "$date"
          },
          "month": {
            $month: "$date"
          },
          "day": 1
        }
      },
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $skip: 0
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$data"
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cclmaI-0G8C)

Comment: Thanks that worked. Had to change `key: -1` to `_id: -1` in sort.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using collection.find() method, use sort method along with that.
like this : `collection.find().sort({created : -1})`

If you want to filter, the look at this once :

```
collection.find({ $expr: {
$eq: [{ $month: "$date" }, 03]
}});
```

Hope this helps!.

Comment: Month 03 is dynamic. It should be calculated from latest available date.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use aggregations, you can use

- `$month` to get the month from date
- `$match` to filter the value
- `$sort` to sort by ASC or DESC
- `$project` to keep or remove fields

here is the code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      month: { $month": "$date"}
    }
  },
  { "$match": { month: 3 } },
  { "$sort": { date: 1}},
  { "$project": { date: 1 } }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A9_bVG4yKhp)**

Comment: Month 3 is dynamic. It should be calculated from latest available date.